# Design of a basic half-adder

Tags: adder, logic-gates

I know that a half-adder is a combination of the gates: XOR, AND.
But **how** are they combined? And can you give a example and explain which one is the XOR and which one is the AND.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=half+adder&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=G9mrVL-8J8aX7Qa2roCoDg&ved=0CEkQsAQ&biw=1280&bih=897 Google is everyone's friend!

Comment: Google 'half-adder'... Wikipedia has an article 'Adder_(electronics)' explaining this aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is everyone's friend: -

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=half+adder&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=G9mrVL-8J8aX7Qa2roCoDg&ved=0CEkQsAQ&biw=1280&bih=897

[image]
<sub>(source: [circuitstoday.com](http://www.circuitstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/half-adder-truth-table-schematic-realization.png))</sub>

S = sum of A and B, C = carry (A and B both 1).

Answer (score 3):

For a half adder with inputs A and B

```
SUM = A XOR B
CARRY = A AND B
```

[image]

<sup>(from [All About Circuits](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_4/chpt_9/2.html))</sup>